# Name of the Android popup opened by long pressing the power button

Tags: interface, android

On Android devices, when you hold the power button for a couple of seconds, a screen pops up with options like “airplane mode”, “silent mode”, “restart”, and “power off”. Is there a name for this screen?

Comment: I think https://android.stackexchange.com might be more suited to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the developer options, it is called the "power menu"

I attached a screenshot of the developer options from Android Nougat

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46883)

Comment: I now edited my answer with what I think is a good answer to that question. Sorry for the inconvenience. I  thought of the question as "How would you name it?", not as "How is it officially named?"